# APC Cache configuration issue Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

I have installed APC cache in my magento website. It has two website(For AU and NZ). After configuring apc with 512M , 4GB memory left. I have setup with this configuration.

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  1
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  1024
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    512M
apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 7200
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

In app/etc/local.xml, I have put this code inside global tag

```
<cache>
     <backend>apc</backend>
     <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
     <prefix>MYSTORE_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Problem is that, After configuring APC , site worked well for 2hr, then it stops working. then if we restart apache, it start working again but after 2 hour it stop again.

Is there is any wrong configuration we did or missed.

Please help

Comment: which version of php, apache, apc(or do you use apcu?)

Comment: Yes Flyingmana, It was apc version issue. Lower apc version is not compatible with 5.4 version. So I installed a latest version of apc. it is in beta but it is working well.

Comment: for opcache functionality you should use the zend opcache module, for 5.4 you need to install it seperate, from 5.5 it is included.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use APC for your backend cache unless you really know what you are doing, you can try redis instead for this. We don't use APC anymore but you can try these settings, start with 128MB to start if just using as an opcode cache.

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.shm_size=128M
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/shm/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your APC configuration other than perhaps setting:

> apc.slam_defense    **0**
>
> apc.stat    **0**

if you are on a production server. You can read more about the settings here: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

The reason why your Magento store crashes is due to **cache fragmentation** and you should not use APC as your first layer cache.

A lot of guides online will tell you to simply increase APCs memory limit to get rid of fragmentation. With Magento, that won't work.

One of the clients I've worked with had the same exact issue, but their store would crash once a week typically on a Monday right after a busy weekend. The store would crash once a week because their Magento was also setup with APC as first layer cache, but with a higher memory limit around 4Gb so it would take longer for the cache to fragment. Once APC reaches high fragmentation %, Magento starts freaking out.

*Here is what you should do:*

1. Keep APC as an opcode cache. 512Mb is more than enough to cache all of Magentos core files and libraries. APC caches opcode by default once it is installed; you do not need to configure Magento. From my experience 512Mb is more than enough to fully cache Magentos opcode (php, phtml files). If you do decide to keep APC for opcode, also increase *apc.num_files_hint* to about 10K.
2. Use Redis for your first layer and database or file for the second layer cache. Redis is a much better option if you are looking to store Magentos generated cache in memory. I won't go into detail of why you should choose Redis over other caching solutions, but keep in mind that all new versions of Magento now support Redis. Plus, you can configure Magento to store user sessions in Redis as well! Here is the official guide: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoECG-UsingRedisasaCacheBackendinMagento.pdf

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I add a ticket regarding this issue to the hosting, they replied , "they are unable to provide support for APC. The only Opcode Cachers they currently support are Xcache and eAccelerator". Can you please tell me which one is good Xcache or eAccelerator ?

Comment: In your original post you mentioned you've installed APC, keep it. All you have to do is remove <backend>apc</backend> from  app/local.xml. Since you have limited memory you can scale down APC from 512MB to 300MB, from what I've seen Magento EE uses about 256MB, but you should still monitor APCs memory usage and adjust it for your store. To monitor APCs usage download the official package here  http://pecl.php.net/package/APC once you extract the package look for a file called apc.php move it to your server and navigate your browser to the apc.php file. There you will see all the cache stats.

Comment: As for Xcache or eAccelerator, I'd say Xcache because it is still relatively maintained as compared to eAccelerator. Last release of eAccelerator was on Jan 26, 2010 while the latest release of Xache was on Oct 10, 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue.I have researched on issue and found apc version that I installed was not compatible with my php version. So I installed latest apc version 3.1.13. Now APC is running well.